# Multiprocessing - PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'botocore.client.S3'>: attribute lookup S3 on botocore.client failed

Tags: python, boto3, python-multiprocessing

The following code gets the error of

> _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'botocore.client.S3'>: attribute lookup S3 on botocore.client failed

```
import boto3
import concurrent.futures as cf

class Boto3:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.s3client = boto3.client("s3")

class C:
    def __init__(self, s3) -> None:
        self.s3 = s3  # this instance variable may have caused the problem
        
    def f(self, a):
        x = self.s3
        return a*a

c = C(Boto3())
```

p = [1,2,3]

```
def run(f, p):
    executor = cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    result = executor.map(f, p)
    print([x for x in result])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(c.f, p)
```

Is it a way to resolve the issue?

---

However, using global variable and functions works?

```
s3 = boto3.client("s3")

def g(a):
    x = s3

....
    result = executor.map(g, p)
```

---

Also, it works if `s3client` is a class variable.

```
class Boto3:
    s3client = boto3.client("s3")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, each of your processes is going to need to create its own Boto3.   You can't share a single one between them.

Comment: I've updated the question. It works when using global variable and function (no class).